# Как избавиться от нуля в массиве?

Tags: массивы, java

При создании абстрактного массива появляется 0, который при вставке нового элемента на его место опускается на следующую позицию в массиве. Почему так происходит и как этого избежать? Можно создавать массив на один элемент больше, но почему так?

```
public class Array {
private int current = 0;
private int [] array;

public Array(int s) {
    array = new int[s];
}

public void insert(int v) {
    if (current < array.length) {
        array[current] = v;
        current++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Array is full");
    }
}
}
```

Если вывести весь массив, то для 6 элементов получается
1
2
3
4
5
6
0

Код, который печатает:

```
public void bypass() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= current; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Код, который вставляет:

```
Array a = new Array(10);
        a.insert(1);
        a.insert(2);
        a.insert(3);
        a.insert(4);
        a.insert(5);
        a.insert(6);
        a.insert(7);
        a.insert(8);
        a.insert(9);
        a.insert(10);
    a.bypass();
```

Comment: покажите код, который вставляет и печатает элементы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

загвоздка в условии `i <= current`. Так как Вы увеличиваете current после добавления элемента, то он указывает на следующий элемент. А ноль там потому что java заботливо занулила массив.

Исправьте условие на `i < current`.